# Is there a way to get local workspaces to work on network shares with VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

My config here is a Macbook with Parallels 9 installed. The VM is running Windows 8 and that runs Visual Studio 2013.

In Visual Studio I am working on my iOS, WP8 and Android projects (Xamarin). The solution is under source control (TFS) and I'm using local workspaces.

Currently the files are hosted inside the VM. Instead I would like to have the files on my Mac's file system so I can access them also if the VM is not running.

However it seems that as soon as I map the solution to the Mac (which then is effectively a network drive), the local workspace seems to stop working and does not track changes anymore.

Is this a general limitation with local workspaces that they don't work on network shares or is there maybe some (hidden) config that could be tweaked?

Answer (score 0):

I did this, it worked for me these are the steps

1) create a local folder on your drive and map it on the network

2) copy it to another folder on your drive

3) open the new pasted folder and run it with VS2013

4) it will pop up for TFS controll

5) Click No and another window pops up press ok

6) If you ever want to go back to TFS just right click on Solution file and click on add to source control

I used windows 7 professional edition and it worked.

Comment: I don't understand: "If you ever want to go back to TFS" - I never want to be without TFS / source control in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Team Explorer Everywhere on the Mac, it's the Java client for TFS. To share the same directory from both machines, you have to inform TFS: the Workspace must be marked as shared.